# Modify body of request to Oauth2 authentication server in Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot app that contains an Oauth2 resource server with opaque tokens. Here's my dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

And my SecurityFilterChain:

```java
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.introspection-uri}")
    String introspectionUri;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.client-id}")
    String clientId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque-token.client-secret}")
    String clientSecret;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .opaqueToken(opaque -> opaque
                            .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri)
                            .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret)
                    )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
```

The issue is that the authentication server I need to use does not have "token" as the name of the parameter in the POST request used to authenticate a token. Instead, let's say it uses "xtoken". This is preventing the authentication of valid tokens, as shown in my logs:

```
Mapped to com.my.app.TestController#test()
HTTP POST <opaque token introspection URI>
Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
Writing [{token=[<12345678...>]}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

How can I modify the body of the request being sent to the authentication server? I initially thought this would be trivial but so far have not found a simple way to configure this.

Comment: You provide with own introspector instead of configuring Spring default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .opaqueToken(opaque -> opaque
                            .introspector(new CustomSpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector(properties))
                    )
            );
    return http.build();
}

static class CustomSpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector extends SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector {

    public CustomSpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties) {
        super(properties.getOpaquetoken().getIntrospectionUri(), properties.getOpaquetoken().getClientId(), properties.getOpaquetoken().getClientSecret());
        setRequestEntityConverter(defaultRequestEntityConverter(URI.create(properties.getOpaquetoken().getIntrospectionUri())));
    }

    private Converter<String, RequestEntity<?>> defaultRequestEntityConverter(URI introspectionUri) {
        return (token) -> {
            //here you can modify the body of the request
            HttpHeaders headers = requestHeaders();
            MultiValueMap<String, String> body = requestBody(token);
            return new RequestEntity<>(body, headers, HttpMethod.POST, introspectionUri);
        };
    }

    private HttpHeaders requestHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        return headers;
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody(String token) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("token", token);
        return body;
    }

}
```

Or you can use the default mechanism

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults())
            );
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector opaqueTokenIntrospector(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties) {
    OAuth2ResourceServerProperties.Opaquetoken opaqueToken = properties.getOpaquetoken();
    SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector springOpaqueTokenIntrospector = new SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector(opaqueToken.getIntrospectionUri(), opaqueToken.getClientId(),
            opaqueToken.getClientSecret());
    springOpaqueTokenIntrospector.setRequestEntityConverter(defaultRequestEntityConverter(URI.create(properties.getOpaquetoken().getIntrospectionUri())));
    return springOpaqueTokenIntrospector;
}

private Converter<String, RequestEntity<?>> defaultRequestEntityConverter(URI introspectionUri) {
    return (token) -> {
        //here you can modify the body of the request
        HttpHeaders headers = requestHeaders();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = requestBody(token);
        return new RequestEntity<>(body, headers, HttpMethod.POST, introspectionUri);
    };
}

private HttpHeaders requestHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return headers;
}

private MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody(String token) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("token", token);
    return body;
}
```

I advice use default mechanism